# move a image in a ouside div when hovering a menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, menu

well, i have 5 elements in a menu, and a little line under this with an image that moves depend on which element you are hovering. By default is under the current website, so it can start in any of the 5 elements.

So if you hover something it moves to that place, if you stop hovering the menu, it comes back to current. But if you hover other element before the current, it goes directly to that point.

All menus have the same part of the begining of the id, for example #fxmenu_1. From 1 to 5, i think is faster to take just the number of the id and avoid writting 5 jquerys.

I tried a little bit, but there is something wrong with my jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id;
    $('#fxmenu_'+id+':not(.totalactive)').hover(function (){
        $('#img').animate({"marginTop": "-70px"},1000, function(){
            $('#img').animate({"marginLeft":+(180*id)+"px"},1000, function(){
                $('#img').animate({"marginTop": "-90px"},1000);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Here you can see my example: http://jsfiddle.net/rzJMv/1/

This is another try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id,
    hovermenu = $('#fxmenu_'+id);
    $(hovermenu).hover(function (){
        $('#img').animate({marginTop: "-70px"},1000, function(){
            $('#img').animate({marginLeft:+(180*id)+"px"},1000, function(){
                $('#img').animate({marginTop: "-90px"},1000);
            });
        });
    }, function() {
        $('#img').removeAttr('style');

    });
});
```

Comment: `id` in your code is `undefined`. Instead of IDs you can use classes.

Comment: In your code you have the following issues 1.id is undefined and don't have specified value. 2. Your menu "fxmenu1_" something like this where as in your script you have used "#fxmenu_" + id.

Comment: yeah, of course, but them with classes, i cant imagine what can i do to let jquery guess what i am hovering.

Comment: I want to take the number of any of the IDs of the menu to use it for the script. Look the other code i wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest using this javascript plugin? 
 
http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/sliding-javascript-menu-highlight-1kb/

It has the functionality you are trying to recreate. Why try to recreate the wheel?

**Edit 1**

Anyway, if you did want to do this with your code, here is a reworking.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pmenu">
    <ul id="bmenul">
        <li><a class="brand" id="fxmenu1_" href="/">LOGO</a> </li>
        <li class="active"><a id="fxmenu_2"  href="/team" title="team">The team</a> </li>
        <li><a id="fxmenu_3" href="/services" title="Servicios">Services</a> </li>
        <li><a id="fxmenu_4" href="/projects" title="Proyectos">Projects</a> </li>
        <li><a id="fxmenu_5" href="/contact" title="Contacto">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="img"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeIndex = $('#bmenul > li.active').index();

    $('#img').css({
        'marginLeft': (180 * activeIndex) + 'px'
    }).show();

    $('#bmenul > li').not('.active').hover(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('#img').stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': (180 * index) + 'px'
        }, 400);
    }, function() {
        $('#img').stop().animate({
            'marginLeft': (180 * activeIndex) + 'px'
        }, 400);
    });
});​
```

**CSS**

```css
...
#img {
    max-height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    display: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzJMv/7/)**

Comment: It has to be that, but somehow the javascript doesnt find the ids. This is my Website. the .totalactive class is defined by php. www.bluenz.com

Comment: this is awesome (irony), I Changed your jsflidde with my real divs, and it works there, then i copied to my website, and nothing happend... http://jsfiddle.net/rzJMv/10/ to http://www.bluenz.com

Comment: Looking at your website I can see it working for me in IE, Chrome and Firefox. Are you still having issues with this?